# Applications of Cauchy's convergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Cauchy's Convergence Theorem:

Let {$P_n$} be a sequence of points and let $d(P_m,P_n)$ be the distance between $P_m$ and $P_n$. Then for a sequence to be convergent, $d(P_m,P_n)$ should $\to$ 0, as $n$ and $m$ become infinite.

I understand the theorem, but if I'm given a sequence, how can I apply this theorem to check if the sequence is Cauchy? I have a midterm tomorrow and I'm positive this will be a question.

The only thing I can think to do would be to some how prove that the distance is always less than some $\epsilon$. But I'm not sure how to even do that. Also, my book doesn't have any problems which require the use of this theorem, so I have nothing to really check any kind of work against. There is only the proof of the formula.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the theorem refers to a complete metric space (if you haven't done metric spaces, I presume your points are real numbers with the usual distances).

For calculations, your intuition is correct: if you can prove that $d(x_n,x_m)<\epsilon$ eventually for all $\epsilon$, then you can conclude that the sequence is Cauchy. However, this is not always required, as you can just take limits as well! Choose your favourite convergent sequence and try it out.

As an example, take your sequence of points to be $P_n=\frac{1}{n}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual metric. Then

$d(P_n,P_m)=\left|\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{m}\right|\leq\left|\frac{1}{n}\right|+\left|\frac{1}{m}\right|\to0 $ as $m,n\to\infty$

If you really love your $\epsilon's$, you can also write it like so. Fix $\epsilon>0$. There is a positive integer $k>0$ such that $\frac{1}{k}<\epsilon$. Given $m,n>2k$ (so that $\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{n}<\frac{1}{k}<\epsilon$), we have

$d(P_n,P_m)=\left|\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{m}\right|\leq\left|\frac{1}{n}\right|+\left|\frac{1}{m}\right|<\frac{1}{2k}+\frac{1}{2k}=\frac{1}{k}<\epsilon$

Your friends in such calculations include the triangle and Cauchy-Schwarz inequalities.

Answer (score 1):

Frequently in analysis, you're given a sequence $\{x_n\}$ which we'd like to show converges.  The problem is that the definition of convergence requires we find a point $x$ so that $\lim_{n \to \infty} d(x,x_n) = 0$ for some $x$ in our metric space.  Cauchy's criteria says that in a complete metric space, it's enough to show that for any $\epsilon > 0$, there's an $N$ so that if $n,m \ge N$, then $d(x_n,x_m) < \epsilon$; that is, we can show convergence without knowing exactly what the sequence is converging to in the first place.

So you use Cauchy's theorem when you're trying to show a sequence converges but don't have a good guess what it converges to.

Comment: Could you give an example? I'm looking for an application of how to find such $N$ for any $\epsilon > 0.$